# OpenCV C++ Mat to Integer

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, video-processing

I'm pretty new to OpenCV, so bear with me.  I'm running a Mac Mini with OSX 10.8.  I have a program that recognizes colors and displays them in binary picture (black and white).  However, I want to store the number of white pixels as an integer (or float, etc.) to compare with other number of pixels.  How can I do this?  Here is my current code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from webcam

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("HSVLeftRed", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("HSVLeftGreen", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);


    while (true) {

        Mat image;
        cap.read(image);
        Mat HSV;
        Mat leftgreen;
        Mat leftred;

        //Left Cropping
        Mat leftimg = image(Rect(0, 0, 640, 720));       

        //Left Red Detection
        cvtColor(leftimg,HSV,CV_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(HSV,Scalar(0,0,150),Scalar(0,0,255), leftgreen);
        //imshow("HSVLeftRed", leftgreen);
        //print pixel type    

        //Left Green Detection
        cvtColor(leftimg,HSV,CV_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(HSV,Scalar(still need to find proper min values),Scalar(still need to find proper max values), leftgreen);
        //imshow("HSVLeftGreen", leftgreen);
        //compare pixel types
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the non-zero pixels, OpenCV has this function `cv::countNonZero`. It takes input the image, whose number of non-zero pixels, we want to calculate and output is number of non-zero pixels(`int`). [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) is the documentation.

In your case, since all the pixels are either black or white, all the non zero pixels will be white pixels.

This is how to use it,

```
int cal = countNonZero(image);
```

Change `image`, as per your code.